# Codeigniter get user who has today's birthday

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter:

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("clients");
$this->db->where("MONTH(Birth_date)","MONTH(NOW())");
$this->db->where("DAY(Birth_date)","DAY(NOW())");
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Anyone can help me How can get a user who has today's birthday? Why my this function is not working?

Comment: please post your birth_date field data type.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this solution for your problem.

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("clients");
$this->db->where("EXTRACT(month FROM `Birth_date`)","MONTH(NOW())");
$this->db->where("EXTRACT(day FROM `Birth_date`)","DAY(NOW())");
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

I hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from("clients");
$this->db->where("date(Birth_date)",date("Y-m-d",time()));
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

`date` used because if `Birth_date` is in timestamp then it won't soo correct result

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$this->db->where('EXTRACT(MONTH_DAY FROM Birth_date)',date('md'));
```